# Browser opens without my control

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

My browser starts to open without my control at the following link:

https:// www. youtube.com/signin_passive?reload=9&reload=9

Do you have any clues on it?

No viruses have been found with Windows defender or Malwarebytes

Comment: This link have some bad behavior!! it keeps reloading the page and adding more &reload=9 at the URL!

Comment: Yes exactly, do you have any advice?

Comment: I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/bu8y64/youtube_will_endlessly_reload_when_i_perform_a/

Comment: After some tests, I found that this behavior occurs if you're using a browser that you're already signed into youtube at, if you aren't signed in, this the link open an error page of youtube without refreshing..
If this usually happens when the browser is totally closed, even the system tray icon -in case of Chrome- then this isn't a bad plug-in of the browser, it may be an advertising software installed on your OS or a bad malware.
Revise your list of installed programs to check if a mystery software is installed, also scan your computer for viruses using any bootable tool like Kaspersky